# How do i create a simple form and show the entered values when user submit data in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to create a form and submit it and show the submitted values in a page. But i am getting error most often, can any one help me to work around this with any simple example or simple link?

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to create a form without REST is

```
<%= form_tag '/some_path' do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :name %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

and then you can get to the value of the text field via `params[:name]`. This will be available in a controller, for example.

```
# routes.rb

match "/something" => "home#something"

# home_controller.rb

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def something
    # this will output raw text/plain with the content submitted via the form
    render :text => params[:name]
  end
end
```

It would be helpful if you could provide exactly what error are you getting and an example of your code.

Comment: @balanv you're welcome, but I highly recommend you take a look at REST, which is usually preferred to the approach I mentioned in the answer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default